# Apache try_files analog

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting, configuration-files

How do I remake this nginx config

```
location / {
    try_files /public/$uri @app;
}

location @app {
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm;
}
```

}

to Apache config?

Comment: This is an interesting question because even php files in /public would be returned as plaintext and location filtering on /public can't be used because if the file doesn't exist it would still be passed to php.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just doing two things.

1. If the file exists in the public sub-directory of root, return it.
2. Otherwise, send it to php.

So in Apache we need to do the test first

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

RewriteCond puts a condition on the following rule, -f means that the file exists. So we know that the file exists in the public sub-directory so apply the rule of rewriting the request to the public sub-directory. The L flag means that Apache will consider this the last rewrite rule and not process any other rewrite rules.

Now for the second part.

```
RewriteRule . "-" [H=application/x-httpd-php]
```

Of course, this assumes that all appropriate apache modules are installed and active, particularly mod_rewrite and that `RewriteEngine on` has already been called. It's worth mentioning that in both nginx and apache there are many more options that must be set for this to work correctly.

Further documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can use (need some tweak I guess):

```
Alias /public /xxxxx/public

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond /xxxxx/public/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond /xxxxx/public/%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule . "-" [H=application/x-httpd-php]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule (.) /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `application/x-httpd-php` is the php handler, It can be different on your setup ( fcgid-script / application/php ...) Check the handler defined by your php setup.